# Is any representation is equivalent to a unitary representation?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose $p$ is a representation which is not unitary in the standard inner product. Now as in Maschke's theorem, we can define a new inner product in which p is unitary.
Now what I do not understand is , by this process , how can I get a new representation say $\phi$ which is unitary in the standard basis and also equivalent to $ p$.

Comment: This only succeeds for _compact_ groups' representations on Hilbert spaces... otherwise the averaging process hard to understand...

Comment: I need this to proof first orthogonality relations for finite groups. In the book 'Representation theory of finite groups' by steinberg, the author has used this to prove the relations in page 37, theorem 4.3.9 .

Comment: Ah, ok, finite implies compact! :)  I think you may be confusing yourself by choosing a basis needlessly... Just look at the inner product, not a basis. Averaging any given inner product over the group gives an invariant inner product. Done. Choose a basis _afterward_, if you must... or don't choose one at all.